# Formula to return TRUE if Criteria Matches?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

The reason I am posting this question is that combining Index and Match functions only searches for first qualifying row from top-down and I am needing to find next row up from current that matches as part of my formula.

The complete formula I am trying to construct is to return TRUE in cell "C4" if equal to the row that has the lowest value in column "A" from just above a value (nonblank) in column "C" to just before numbers in column "B" go above 55. So in this case, it would return TRUE in cell "C4" because for the blue highlighted area value 28.28 is lowest in column "A".

Secondarily not sure if `INDIRECT` function is best to use since I have a few hundred of these in my sheet. Is this a resource hog when I need these to calculate quickly???

I have it posted here and am posting it here because I am trying to get this to work in Sheets which I know is often different than Excel.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_win10-mso_2016/formula-to-return-true-if-criteria-matches/02834e93-c29f-449d-ace0-98722c399e63?tm=1568399215380

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: also pls explain the "column "B" go above 55" in more detail

Answer (score 0):

perhaps like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A=MIN(FILTER(A1:A, B1:B<55)), TRUE, ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you.  Just tried it and doesn't allow for the "T" in cell C6.  If so would it only be searching for lowest value in column A for rows 3 through 5?  Getting very close. :)

Comment: try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A5=MIN(FILTER(A1:A5, B1:B5<55)), TRUE, ))`

Comment: I will construct a share copy later today to better demonstrate.  It is a pogression, so for that reason I am trying to keep it simplified.  I will show you what my project is and try to detail it out and explain so we are on the same page.  Thanksin advance for you help!

Comment: Here is the editable link I promised.  I lost access to this over the weekend, so I apologize for not responding sooner. Please let me know if you have additional questions, but I think all the information is included in the sheets link.  Thank you!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZHx1K2oe_AHip9jCO3aP_Wi5gxCi_6-ZJoMaVbW_878/edit?usp=sharing